# Как завершить создание текстового документа если заданное условие не выполнено

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Товарищи вопрос в следующем: есть в коде конструкция вида

```
for line in lines:
    if line.find ('Информирование') != -1:  # то что ищем
        t5 = line [0:40]  # определяет глубину
        print (t5)  # выводим на экран проверяем
        break
```

Которая занимается поиском в документе слова Информирование, после чего строку с 0 по 40 символ заносит в результирующий документ и есть программа в которой таких конструкций несколько

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import setuptools

name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла: ")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines = f.readlines ()  # читаем его построчно
t1 = lines [6]
t2 = lines [-5]
t3 = lines [-6]
# -------- поиск встроке
#a=t1.find ([1], [2])
# --------
for line in lines:
    if line.find ('Информирование') != -1:  # то что ищем
        t5 = line [0:40]  # определяет глубину
        print (t5)  # выводим на экран проверяем
        break
#--------
for line in lines:
    if line.find ('НА НР') != -1:  # то что ищем
        t4 = line [7:40]  # определяет глубину
        print (t4)  # выводим на экран проверяем
        break
name1: str = input ("Введите имя исходящего файла: ")
f = open (name1, "w+")
# f.write(str(t1 + "\n" +  t2))
f.write ('реквизит верхний// ' + str (t1))
f.write ('реквизит нижний// ' + str (t2))
f.write ('дата// ' + str (t3))
f.write ('\nнанр// ' + str (t4))
f.write ('\n// ' + str (t5))
f.close ()
```

В следствии выполнения этой программой действий и нахождения слова Информирование программа завершается правильно и создаёт файл, в случае если словарных конструкций находящихся в циклах нет, то возникает такая ошибка

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/АБИ/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    f.write ('\n// ' + str (t5))
NameError: name 't5' is not defined*
```

и файл не создаётся, как сделать так, что бы вне зависимости от выполнения условий циклов 1. файл создавался 2. была подсказка что то-то или то-то не найдено в файле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в предспоследней срочке

```
f.write ('\n// ' + str (t5))
```

но `t5` появится, только если отработает условие

```
if line.find ('Информирование') != -1:  # то что ищем
```

Самое простое - проверять `t5` :

```
if 't5' in globals(): # 't5' in locals()
  f.write ('\n// ' + str (t5))
```

или создать значение по умолчанию:

```
import setuptools

name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла: ")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines = f.readlines ()  # читаем его построчно
t1 = lines [6]
t2 = lines [-5]
t3 = lines [-6]
t5 = "" # создаем с значением по умолчанию
# остальной код
f.write ('\n// ' + str (t5))
f.close ()
```

Кстати для `t4`у вас может быть та же проблема

Comment: Классный способ принял, понял, протестировал